# Visual Studio 2013: javascript debugging (windows console application)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, windows

Sometimes I need to write an auxiliary scripts (using **javascript**) for routine operations
I create **1.js** file and run it using

```
cscript 1.js
```

or insert this line in batch script.
But I could not find a way to debug this javascript in Visual Studio.
Is it possible?
Is there any other way to create a javascript console local application in Visual Studio **2013** and debug it (watch variables and set breakpoints)?